# Is it possible to automatically publish a post once a woo-commerce product is published?

Tags: posts, woocommerce-offtopic

I want my site to be able to automatically create and publish a new post once a woocommerce product is created and published. I want the post to have the same featured image of the published product as well as the same description.

On other-words products and posts should be generated simultaneously including same featured image and description.

Answer (score 1):

WC products are posts themselves, so you could use:

```
add_action('publish_post', 'wpse_publish_post_with_product');
```

Within the new function, you'd have a check for `post_type`. If the `post_type` that was just published is a WC product, then grab the image and description from that post, and use `wp_insert_post()` to publish a Post with the same info.

**Side note:** I'm not sure what your goal is with publishing a Post in addition to a Product. Since both URLs will contain roughly the same information, you're likely to run into SEO problems with duplicate content. If you could elaborate on your goal, there might be a better, more SEO-friendly way to achieve it.